# How to move along a 2d grid in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Working on a problem that I am not sure how to address. Problem asks to make a function which moves an arrow in a 2D grid using the strings L(left),R(right),F(forward). The arrow starts off at the position (0,0) pointing up. For example given the string 'RFLF',(1,1) would be returned since that is where the arrow would end up, pointing north. Just to be clear the problem does not care for the final direction of the arrow rather it only cares about the position that is returned. L and R only affect the direction the arrow is pointing unless accompanied by F to make it go in that direction.

Comment: It sounds more like the question involves moving a vector of length 1 around on the grid, than a point.  The vector begins as (0,0) >> (0,1). A L move transforms the vector to (0,0) >> (-1,0). A F move would then transform the vector to (-1,0) >> (-2,0), yes?

Comment: @neutrino_logic So the L and R actually don't move forward unless an F follows it. An L would not transform the vector (0,0) to (-1,0) unless the string 'LF' was inputted. If just an L was the input, the point would just be facing left but still sitting at (0,0)

Comment: A point can't face any direction without extra information, so the syntax (0,0) >> (-1,0) would mean an arrow with its origin at (0,0) pointing towards (-1,0). Note also the function would have to return this directional information in some form, it couldn't just return a point. This vector approach is one way to do this.

Comment: @neutrino_logic Ah okay I kind of understand what you mean. The question does not necessarily want the directional information returned. I guess a better way of explaining what I want to do it is in fact thinking about it as an arrow starting off at (0,0), pointing north and then lets say given a string like ''RFFLF', (2,1) would be returned since thats the point it's sitting at now. The question does not ask what direction this arrow would be facing in the end.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to make a class called Point and run everything through that:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y:int , facing: str):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.facing = facing

    def left(self):
        if self.facing == 'N':
            self.facing = 'W'
        elif self.facing == 'W':
            self.facing = 'S'
        elif self.facing == 'S':
            self.facing = 'E'
        else:
            self.facing = 'N'

    def right(self):
        if self.facing == 'N':
            self.facing = 'E'
        elif self.facing == 'E':
            self.facing = 'S'
        elif self.facing == 'S':
            self.facing = 'W'
        else:
            self.facing = 'N'

    def forward(self):
        if self.facing == 'N':
            self.y += 1
        elif self.facing == 'E':
            self.x += 1
        elif self.facing == 'S':
            self.y -= 1
        else:
            self.x -= 1    

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"(x,y) = {(self.x,self.y)}  direction = {self.facing}"
```

So if you instantiate an object of this class, you can then translate a string fairly easily into a series of moves, for example:

```
a = Point(0,0,'N')
for x in 'RFFLF':
    if x = 'L':
        a.left()
    elif x = 'R':
        a.right()
    else:
        a.forward()
    print(repr(a))
```

Note this is a pretty crude approach. This all might be more concisely implemented with an enumeration (N,E,S,W) or by using something tricky like a vector transformation matrix.